# Python install issue

Tags: python, installation

Totally new to Python (some basic HTML in secondary school) but as part of a Maths degree we are required to use Python and specifically Anaconda.

I have attempted to install it on my Windows 7 laptop and it has not gone well. Opening Anaconda prompt returns :" '`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` "

A google search recommended going into the file directory but using where Anaconda (both capitalised and not) returns "`INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`". I can't find it in either Program Files folder, or any where else. Also should mention I did not tick the option to create a new PATH during installation as the wizard recommended against it, and I cannot reinstall as every time it says "`Error 'Destination Folder' contains 2 spaces. This can cause problems with several Conda packages, and is thus disabled. Please install to a path without the spaces.`".

Finally, the version I am trying to install is Anaconda 2 5.0.0 as recommended by the tutor.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's possibly gone into `c:/Users/your_user_name/AppData/Local/...`. You'll need to unhide hidden folders to see `AppData`. However, I'm not sure exactly what will fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Anaconda, then reinstall from [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.0-Windows-x86_64.exe). Or if you have previously installed Python on your computer separately then uninstall it and during the Anaconda installation it be reinstalled for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error 'Destination Folder' contains 2 spaces. This can cause problems with several Conda packages and is thus disabled. Please install to a path without the spaces.
```

To overcome this error, rename your file but keep in mind that there can't be any space in it.